# How to make objects draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed this tutorial on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vs-SF2UWy4&t=28s
Sorry in advance if I made any mistakes here, I just started learning but I have to make draggable and droppable furniture
[I can't move the objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9CCL.png)

here are the code that I wrote

```html
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="home">
            <div class="image"><img src="A.png" width="200px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="B.PNG" width="240px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="C.PNG" width="250px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="D.PNG" width="210px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="E.PNG" width="290px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="F.PNG" width="240px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="G.PNG" width="250px" alt=""></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="H.PNG" width="220px" alt=""></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
       $("#home .image").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to import the jQuery UI javascript. At the moment you're only importing the CSS. Take a look at [this](https://code.jquery.com/ui/) for links to CDN or downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See working example in snippet. You need to include `jQuery` before `jQuery UI`.

```js
    $(function (){
       $(".image").draggable();
    });
```

```css
.image {
background:yellow;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
        <div id="home">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```